# Spark find previous value on each iteration of RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

I've following code :-

```
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("db", "table").select("id", "date", "gpsdt").where("id=? and date=? and gpsdt>? and gpsdt<?", entry(0), entry(1), entry(2) , entry(3))
val rddcopy = rdd.sortBy(row => row.get[String]("gpsdt"), false).zipWithIndex()
rddcopy.foreach { records =>
  {
    val previousRow = (records - 1)th row
    val currentRow = records
// Some calculation based on both rows 
    }
}
```

So, Idea is to get just previous \ next row on each iteration of RDD. I want to calculate some field on current row based on the value present on previous row. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

EDIT II: Misunderstood question below is how to get tumbling window semantics but sliding window is needed. considering this is a sorted RDD

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._
sortedRDD.sliding(2)
```

should do the trick. Note however that this is using a DeveloperAPI.

alternatively you can

```
val l = sortedRdd.zipWithIndex.map(kv => (kv._2, kv._1))
val r = sortedRdd.zipWithIndex.map(kv => (kv._2-1, kv._1))
val sliding = l.join(r)
```

rdd joins should be inner joins (IIRC) thus dropping the edge cases where the tuples would be partially null

OLD STUFF:

how do you do identify the previous row? RDDs do not have any sort of stable ordering by themselves. if you have an incrementing dense key you could add a new column that get's calculated the following way `if (k % 2 == 0) k / 2 else (k-1)/2` this should give you a key that has the same value for two successive keys. Then you could just group by.

But to reiterate there is no really sensible notion of `previous` in most cases for RDDs (depending on partitioning, datasource etc.)

EDIT: so now that you have a zipWithIndex and an ordering in your set you can do what I mentioned above. So now you have an `RDD[(Int, YourData)]` and can do

```
rdd.map( kv => if (kv._1 % 2 == 0) (kv._1 / 2, kv._2) else ( (kv._1 -1) /2, kv._2 ) ).groupByKey.foreach (/* your stuff here /*)
```

if you reduce at any point consider using `reduceByKey` rather than `groupByKey().reduce`

Comment: Hi, I've edited my question to get sorted RDD . So , now I hope it is clear what exactly I'm looking for

Comment: cool. See edit above on how it might work now. just be aware that this is just back of the napkin stuff and I haven't verified

Comment: Error :- value % is not a member of com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow

Comment: you'll probably have to do it on `rddcopy` rather than `rdd`

Comment: Yes I tried on rddcopy only. for rdd it gives an error :- value _1 is not a member of com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow

Comment: can you check the type of RDD copy? It might be rather `RDD[(CassandraRow, Int)]` rather than `RDD[(Int, CassandraRow)]` if so you'll have to adjust the code with the correct tuple usage

Comment: val rddcopy: RDD[(CassandraRow, Long)]

Comment: ah ok. sorry for some reason I thought `zipWithIndex` would append the `Long` Index on the left instead of the right. just switch around the tuple indices and make sure you return the index on the left in the `map` becasuse `groupByKey` assumes an `RDD[(K,V)]` and will group on `K`. So you'll want an `RDD[(Long, CassandraRow)]]` before calling `groupByKey` not the other way around

Comment: if you look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions you'll see that after the `groupByKey` you have a `RDD[(K, Iterable[V])]` so in your `foreach` you'll have tuples of `Long` and `Iterable[CassandraRow]` you can work with those `Iterables` as you can with any other it is at that point executor local and a regular scala collection

Comment: Lets say rows are A,B,C,D,E (sorted order) . I want (A,nopair),(B,A),(C,B),(D,C),(E,D) but your query gives result as (A,nopair),(C,B),(E,D). I want successive grouping for each row mapped with its previous row.

Comment: I mentioned in my very first question query that I need previous row on each particular iteration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168560/discussion-between-aditya-jain-and-dominic-egger).