# Scala Spark map by pairs of RDD elements

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, difference

What is the best practice to iterate through an RDD in Spark getting both the previous and the current element? The same as the `reduce` function but returning and RDD instead of a single value.

For instance, given:

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("date_values.txt").
          map {
             case Array(val1, val2, val3) =>
                Element(DateTime.parse(val1), val2.toDouble)
          }
```

The output should be a new RDD with the differences in val2 attributes:

`Diff(date, current.val2 - previous.val2)`

With the `map` function I can only get the current element, and with the `reduce` function I can only return 1 element not and RDD.
I could use the `foreach` function saving in temporal variables the previous value but I don't think this would follow the Scala-Spark guidelines.

What do you think is the most appropriate way to handle this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34146907/operate-on-neighbor-elements-in-rdd-in-spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by Dominic Egger in this thread is what I was looking for:

[Spark find previous value on each iteration of RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49730706/spark-find-previous-value-on-each-iteration-of-rdd)

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._
sortedRDD.sliding(2)
```

or using Developer API:

```
val l = sortedRdd.zipWithIndex.map(kv => (kv._2, kv._1))
val r = sortedRdd.zipWithIndex.map(kv => (kv._2-1, kv._1))
val sliding = l.join(r)
```